# Android Google Calendar not adding event

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I have this code in adding events in Android Google calendar but it seems it is not adding when I disable the SPlanner. Is there some issue with Google Calendar and SPlanner?

```
 // Format the start and end time
                                long startMillis = 0;
                                long endMillis = 0;
                                Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                                Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();

                                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale
                                                .getDefault());
                                formatter.setLenient(false);
                                Date startDate = formatter
                                        .parse("2013-10-28 16:00:00");
                                beginTime.setTime(startDate);
                                startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();

                                Date endDate = formatter
                                        .parse("2013-10-28 16:01:00");
                                endTime.setTime(endDate);
                                endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
                                        startMillis);
                                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
                                        endMillis);
                                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,
                                        "Testing title");
                                values.put(
                                        CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,
                                        "Testing description");
                                values.put(
                                        CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID,
                                        calendarId);
                                values.put(
                                        CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,
                                        TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
                                values.put(
                                        CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM,
                                        1);

                                Uri eventsUri = Uri
                                        .parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
                                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                                Uri uri = cr.insert(eventsUri, values);

                                String eventId = uri.getLastPathSegment();

                                // reminder insert
                                Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri
                                        .parse("content://com.android.calendar/reminders");
                                values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put("event_id",
                                        Long.parseLong(eventId));
                                values.put("method", 1);
                                values.put("minutes", 10);
                                cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values);

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "event id=" + eventId,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: did u check whether you are getting proper Calendar id ??

Comment: Hi yes. I have a alertdialog where the user selects the correct calendar to populate.

Comment: Are u getting any exception?? coz same piece of code works for me in both Samsung S2 and Nexus 7